# Comma separated selectors

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of a hard time explaining what I want to do. Here's my CSS code:

```
div#addannouncmentdiv form button,input,textarea{
    width:50%;
}
```

But for some reason the inputs and the text areas even not in the `div#addannouncmentdiv form` still have the 50% width property. I know I can do this:

```
div#addannouncmentdiv form button,div#addannouncmentdiv form input,div#addannouncmentdiv form textarea{
    width: 50%;
}
```

But is there a shorter way than writing the `div#addannouncmentdiv form` every time again and again?

Comment: That's right, yes, commas separate whole selectors, not just the last word. So there is no other way, other than using shorter ids. Or something like LESS.

Comment: Nope.  That's how you do it.  You could shorten it to `#addannouncmentdiv form` or `#addannouncmentdiv` because IDs should be unique, but that's how you would do it.

Comment: You can do it in another way, but it requires tools like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: Who done changed my very descriptive title?

Comment: You might be able to use `#addannouncmentdiv form > *` if all button, input etc are all siblings, and directly under the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example in your question is correct:

```
div#addannouncmentdiv form button,
div#addannouncmentdiv form input,
div#addannouncmentdiv form textarea {
width: 50%;
}
```

In fact, the following would be just as good:

```
#addannouncmentdiv button,
#addannouncmentdiv input,
#addannouncmentdiv textarea {
width: 50%;
}
```

If you add a class to your `<form>` such as:

```
<form class="aad">
```

then you can simply use:

```
.aad button,.aad input,.aad textarea {
width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Why should I add a class? Instead I could just change the ID to aad. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 6):

This can't be done in the current version of CSS. What you're looking for is a CSS Pre-Processor like SaSS or LESS.

SaSS / LESS

```
div#addannouncmentdiv form {
    button, input, textarea {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Edit:

As @Mr.Alien says. This can be cleaned up to:

```
#addannouncmentdiv {
    button, input, textarea {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK; is this the same in LESS and SCSS? I wasn't sure.

Comment: +1:  I would suggest moving to SaSS if you're writing a lot of styling, because Micah is exactly write and standard CSS can get very verbose.

Comment: You can get rid of `form`, and `div` element in the selector to control specificity, as he is anyways using an id and am sure he might not be using the same id for other elements on other pages.